# How do I prove Strang & Herman's definition of Multivariable Differentiability implies Stewart's?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have tried to prove that the definition of differentiability used by [Gilbert Strang & Edwin “Jed” Herman](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/14%3A_Differentiation_of_Functions_of_Several_Variables/14.4%3A_Tangent_Planes_and_Linear_Approximations) implies the definition used by Stewart/Ron Larson.
I can't seem to do it. [Here is my proof](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N0ENybW27yqgO3pgdlmO5jFSoSff90V0/view) so far.
Can someone say whether my definition of the epsilons in Stewart is wrong or what the next step should be?
Thanks.

Edit:

A function f(x,y) is differentiable at a point $(x_0,y_0 )$ if, for all points (x,y) in a δ disk around P, we can write
$f(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0 )+f_x (x_0,y_0 )(x-x_0 )+f_y (x_0,y_0 )(y-y_0 )+E(x,y),$
where the error term E satisfies
$$lim_{(x,y)→(x_0,y_0 ) }  \frac{E(x,y)}{((x-x_0 )^2+(y-y_0 )^2)^{1/2}}=0.$$

I want to show this implies

A function f(x,y) is differentiable at a point $(x_0,y_0 )$ if,
$$Δz=f_x (x_0,y_0 )Δx+f_y (x_0,y_0 )Δy+ε_1 Δx+ε_2 Δy,$$
where $ε_1→0$ and $ε_2→0$ as $(Δx,Δy)→(0,0)$ which is to say as $(x,y)→(x_0,y_0 )$.

I defined $ε_1=E/2Δx$ and $ε_2=E/2Δy$.  Now I want to show both epsilons go to 0 as Deltas go to 0.

I updated the link to work now but just in case; My proof is on GDrive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N0ENybW27yqgO3pgdlmO5jFSoSff90V0/view
or dropbox
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ycn6lqrtats16as/differentiability%20proofs%20are%20equivalent.pdf?dl=0

Comment: We cannot access the link to your proof. Could you write it down in your question?

Comment: Yes, please make the effort to type things in here so that we can read them.

Comment: I believe the Stewart/Larson definition is just wrong. Take $f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)^{3/4} = r^{3/4} = F(r)$. This function is differentiable (according to the correct definition) at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ with derivative $0$. Set this equal to $\epsilon_1 x + \epsilon_2 y$, and write this in polar coordinates. I believe you'll show that $\epsilon_1 = \phi(r)(A\cos\theta+B\sin\theta)$ and $\epsilon_2 = \phi(r)(A\sin\theta-B\cos\theta)$, where $(\ln \phi)'(r) = (F'(r)-1)/r$. Solving this you see that $\epsilon_j\to 0$ as $r\to 0$ is impossible.

Comment: No, I retract that. Take $\epsilon_1 = \dfrac{F(r)}{r}\cos\theta$ and $\epsilon_2 = \dfrac{F(r)}r\sin\theta$. These do go to $0$. There's a typo in my earlier comment, too; $F(r)=r^{3/2}$ is the correct formula.